# VSTS: finding project-wide changes between two change lists or labels

Tags: azure-devops, diff, changelist

I have a large project that is hosted in VSTS. I'd like see the differences in all files, project-wide, between two change lists. (It would also be helpful to do the same between two labels, since I have labels at the two points of interest.)

We have a problem that manifests between one build of our product and another; one way to go searching for the issue is to comprehensively review the code that changed between those two builds.

How can I show the differences in all files, project-wide, between one change list and another?

I've tried this:

```
tf diff . /recursive /version:100~150
```

and it seems to work, but it takes a very long time; and the output is a plain text diff.  Can I browse the changes graphically, like in BeyondCompare or the IDE? Anything I can do to speed up the comparison?

Comment: Do you mean "`tf compare`" or `tf diff`? Can you show the screen shot of the command you execute and it's output? And what if you use VS to compare the differences?

Comment: Indeed, `tf diff`; sorry about that. I'd rather not post a screen shot, since it would contain file names and source code. Can you tell me what it is you'd like to see or know about the command output?

In my question, I'm asking how to do something. Your question is "have I tried doing that in VS".  Can you tell me how to do this action inside VS? If you can, then you would provide an answer to my question.

Comment: Why I asked you try with VS since you said you use tf cli with longer time. For compare the changes in VS, you can right click Compare on (https://imgur.com/a/XWKNE) on a file, a folder or a TFVC repo for comparison.